# Rails to find average and no.of rating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a newbie in rails and I could able understand how to find average and no.of ratings.

My tables look like this 
books table

```
 id Name      author
   1  rails    raj
   2  ruby     ravi
```

And by rating table looks like

```
  id user_id   book_id     r1     r2    r3    r4
      1   1         1      4       5     6    7
      2   1          2     8       9     5    6
      3   2          1     4       5     6    7
```

Now I would like to display in index.html.page

```
    Name   author     avg                          no.of ratings
    rails   raj      (4+4)+(5+5)+(6+6)+(7+7)/4          2
    ruby     ravi     8+9+5+6/4                         1
```

So how can I do this I could able to understand the Rails Query language I wanted all this ratings to be done in my books controller.

Can any one please guide me to do this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rails Calculations helper functions:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html

For your use here, look at the [average()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average) function Rails provides:

If you have your model associations properly, you will be able to do things like:

```
@user = User.find(1)
@user.ratings.average('r1')
```

Comment: maybe add the `count` too for completness? it is part of the question

Comment: Can explain in details I want to display these things with out the user authentication it will be on the freepage. I dont want to find the avg of only r1 I want find the average of r1+r2+r3+r4